HTTPS API Calls Failing in WiX MSI Installer While Working in Console App
I’m developing a custom installer using the WiX Toolset for a .NET Framework 4.8 application. During the installation process, I need to make an HTTPS API call. The API call works perfectly in a standalone console application but consistently fails when executed from the MSI installer.
Problem Details:
The API call works with both HTTP and HTTPS in the console application.
In the MSI installer, HTTP requests succeed, but HTTPS requests fail with the following error

Error :
An error occurred while server Configration : WebException
occurred during API call:
https://{Domain}:443/api/RPA/RpaSetupLog
Status: ReceiveFailure
Response:
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An
unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Stack trace: at System.Net. HttpWebRequest.GetResponseO
at CustomActions. CustomActions. SendDataToApi(String
protocol, String domainOrlp, String port, String jsonData,
String rootCertificateString, String
intermediateCertificateString, String
endDomainCertificateString) in
Occurred at line: O

So the problem is, I had a Wix installer for that I have MSI installer, in that when I try to call API with https protocol, it give me error, but in normal http it succeeds and the when I create one console app, with same parameter, and same function and try to call it succeeds, I got problem, with https in .msi installer, I also add this line
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

The same in console app, it works, but in MSI installer it fails.
Checked Certificates:
Ensured that the server uses a valid certificate. For self-signed certificates, I’ve manually installed the root, intermediate, and domain certificates in the production system's certificate store.
Tested on Different Environments:

On my local machine, both the console app and MSI installer work fine.
On the production system:

Console app works for both HTTP and HTTPS.
MSI installer fails for HTTPS.
Network Connectivity:



Verified that the production system can resolve and ping the API domain.
HTTP requests from the MSI installer succeed, indicating network access is available.
Code:
private static bool SendDataToApi(string protocol, string domainOrIp, string port, string jsonData)
{
    string apiUrl = $"{protocol}://{domainOrIp}:{port}/api/RPA/RpaSetupLogs";

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Timeout = 30000;

        // Enable TLS 1.2
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        // Bypass SSL Validation (Tried this as a workaround)
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(jsonData);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"API call failed with status: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"WebException: {webEx.Message}, Status: {webEx.Status}");
        throw;
    }
}

Environment Details:

Local System:

Windows 10

.NET Framework 4.8

HTTPS works in both Console App and MSI Installer.



Production System:

Windows Server 2019

HTTPS works in Console App but fails in MSI Installer.

HTTP works fine in both Console App and MSI Installer.




What I Need Help With:

Why does the HTTPS request fail in the MSI installer but work in the console application?

Could it be related to the installer’s execution context, permissions, or environment settings? If so, how do I debug or resolve this?

Are there specific configurations required for the WiX installer to support HTTPS calls during installation?


Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

You should provide the .wxs code that shows how the CustomAction is defined. The user context could make a huge difference.

<CustomAction Id="CallAPI" BinaryKey="CustomActionsBin" DllEntry="callapiexe" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"/>

Could it be that your custom action is executed as "system" (i.e. with different user profile). To reproduce: run your console app as system (i.e. under that account under which the installation happens).
Or you can run your action as the current user. Then the result should match your console app.
<CustomAction 
  ...
  Impersonate="yes"
  ...
/>

BTW you probably don't actually need a separate console app, I think you could use Debugger.Launch and Debugger.Break to start the debugger from the custom action.

there have only one account only , in that i run my consol app in same user and also install the .msi installer in the same user

also i use this
<CustomAction Id="CallAPI" BinaryKey="CustomActionsBin" DllEntry="callapiexe" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"/>

postgres:
  connection:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://your-postgresql-server:5444/your-database"
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}


I'm getting fed in the a any advice

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
